# How to build mqtt broker from scratch?

Tags: protocols, mqtt

I need to build a MQTT broker with basic functions but I cannot find any documents about MQTT broker.

Anyone have any idea how to do this? What do I need to read?

Firstly, I just want broker can accept connection using `CONNECT` and `CONNACK`.

Comment: Why do you want to write your own broker?

Comment: I want to know how mqtt broker work. My mentor wants me to understand and implement a broker.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question then...

Comment: Yeah. My task includes how to implement a broker. I may use an existing broker but I want to know how they can implement it. Is it good?

Comment: See point 3 of the asking on topic questions guide - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4):

The MQTT specification is available [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html), this will outline the protocol you will need to implement.

If your question is more generically, "How do I implement a network protocol?" then I would have to ask why you think you need to write your own broker and not just use one of the existing ones available. Even if the existing open source brokers don't do exactly what you want, adapting one of these will be much easier than starting from scratch. Brokers like [Mosca](http://www.mosca.io/) and [Moquetta](http://andsel.github.io/moquette/) allow themselves to be embedded into other applications.

If you still feel you need to write your own then I would start by picking one of the existing open source brokers and see how they have gone about it, picking one in a language similar to the one you intend to use would be the best bet.